# Rails 5 Reloader Sequence: to_run and to_prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The code base is Rails 5-0-stable, note that the behaviour is different on Rails 4.2

Here's the source code in the reloader:

```
# File: activesupport/lib/active_support/reloader.rb

to_run(:after) { self.class.prepare! }

# Initiate a manual reload
def self.reload!
  executor.wrap do
    new.tap do |instance|
      begin
        instance.run!
      ensure
        instance.complete!
      end
    end
  end
  prepare!
end
```

From here, we know that `to_prepare` runs after the `run!` method;

Furthermore, in one of the initialisers, we have:

```
# File: railties/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb

  # Set routes reload after the finisher hook to ensure routes added in
  # the hook are taken into account.
  initializer :set_routes_reloader_hook do |app|
    reloader = routes_reloader
    reloader.execute_if_updated
    self.reloaders << reloader
    app.reloader.to_run do
      # We configure #execute rather than #execute_if_updated because if
      # autoloaded constants are cleared we need to reload routes also in
      # case any was used there, as in
      #
      #   mount MailPreview => 'mail_view'
      #
      # This means routes are also reloaded if i18n is updated, which
      # might not be necessary, but in order to be more precise we need
      # some sort of reloaders dependency support, to be added.
      require_unload_lock!
      reloader.execute
    end
  end
```

From here we can see that, the routes_reloader is to_run in the `to_run` callback.. Therefore, the current call sequence is:

```
routes_reloader.reload!
prepare!
```

However, prepare! is also defined to run before:

```
# File: railties/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb
  initializer :run_prepare_callbacks do |app|
    app.reloader.prepare!
  end
```

So when boot-up, the call sequence is:

```
prepare!
routes_reloader.reload!
```

So my question here is:

1. What's the intention for `prepare!` method?
2. Why `prepare!` is called before routes reload when first time Rails loads, but after routes reload when hot-reload happened?